# Ho do I send each tag value in onclick="pageRedirect()" function in JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

How can I send and get value of each tag in on click function using jQuery .

HTML

```
    <div class="ui labels">
        <div class="ui basic large label" id="search" onclick="pageRedirect()" style="cursor: pointer">aerial</div>
        <div class="ui basic large label" id="search" onclick="pageRedirect()" style="cursor: pointer">architecture</div>
        <div class="ui basic large label" id="search" onclick="pageRedirect()" style="cursor: pointer">background</div>
        <div class="ui basic large label" id="search" onclick="pageRedirect()" style="cursor: pointer">blue</div>
        <div class="ui basic large label" id="search" onclick="pageRedirect()" style="cursor: pointer">board</div>
        <div class="ui basic large label" id="search" onclick="pageRedirect()" style="cursor: pointer">view</div>
    </div>
```

```
jQuery

<script>
    function pageRedirect() {
    var str1 = "/content/myproject/en/home/asset-library.html?fulltext=";
    var getval = $("#search").text().trim();
    var res = str1.concat(getval);
        window.open(res, "_self");

    }
</script>
```

When I click any tag I am getting only first tag value in "fulltaxt=aerial", I thing I am always getting first tag value because of same "id". How can get only those tag value which I clicking.
I want to do in jQuery.

Comment: You cannot have multiple tags with the same id. You can use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do click function with selector like this:

```js
$("#search").click(function() {
  let text = $(this).text();
  console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: ids are supposed to be singular.

Comment: Can use class, $(".search").click(function() {
  let text = $(this).text();
  console.log(text);
});

Comment: use class instead id if you want singular